# Static field generic constraints

Tags: java, generics

I am assuming its not possible, but is there a way of having a static field defined as such:

```
private final static Map<Class<T>, Class<? extends XmlAdapter<T, ?>>>
```

Such that it is know that if you get Class it will be a class that extends XmlAdapter? Or would this map need to be wrapped in a class with generic methods to ensure this constraint is maintained?

Comment: Thank you, that basically answers what I was asking.

Comment: I asked myself the same question actually ;)

Answer (score 0):

`?` would be pretty useless, because it would prevent you from putting values into the map. If you want to change the contents of the map, you have to provide a type parameter for the values-part too.